# Python: Returning only hosts/a href with my HTML parser

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have an HTML parser that doesn't use any external libraries or packages (such as Beautiful Soup, etc). It works and here it takes a command line html file and returns only the text.

I want to modify it, or have it have a function that **returns only the host names, such as HOST in < a href "HOST"> tag**; have it return just hosts and only top level directory ones like 'stackoverflow.com' etc.

```
class _DeHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.__text = []

def handle_data(self, data):
    text = data.strip()
    if len(text) > 0:
        text = sub('[ \t\r\n]+', ' ', text)  #probably alter here?
        self.__text.append(text + ' ')

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'p':
        self.__text.append('\n\n')
    elif tag == 'br':
        self.__text.append('\n')

def handle_startendtag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'br':
        self.__text.append('\n\n')

def text(self):
    return ''.join(self.__text).strip()


def dehtml():  #have it pass line?
    try:
        parser = _DeHTMLParser()

        f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')  #not argv[1] but stdin all?
        text = f.read()
        f.close()

        parser.feed(text)
        parser.close()
        return parser.text()
    except:
        print_exc(file=stderr)
        return text
```

Right now I can call dehtml() and it runs returns the text-only/no tags version.

To make it try to also print out hosts, I added this to def handle_starttag

```
if tag == 'a href':
        self.__text.append()
```

to see if it would, as a first attempt, append also the host names, but no luck. I believe the issue is in my handle_data part, specifically in the regex bit - is this correct?

Comment: what's your actual question then?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I apologize if it wasn't clear. Right now it returns text outside of tags and I want it to, instead or as an added functionality, to return only the host names *inside* a href tags, such as returning HOST in <a href="HOT"> link </a>

Comment: Should I do something along the lines of, inside handle_starttag, if tag == a href then print?

Comment: ah, I suppose what I meant was what's the problem with your attempt to make what you want to happen, happen?

Comment: you should do *something* yes, and when you get stuck ask *that* question :)

Comment: update your question with your (failed) attempt and you are much more likely to get help, as then it does not look like you are just asking people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `handle_starttag` method has all the information you need to track hosts. You need to parse urls so add this to the top

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

Then add a container to hold the hosts when you initialize

```
def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.__text = []
    self.hosts = set()
```

Then grab the hosts when you are in a starttag. (*edit: mistakenly used attr as a dict*)

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'p':
        self.__text.append('\n\n')
    elif tag == 'br':
        self.__text.append('\n')
    elif tag == 'a':
        for name, value in attrs:
            if name == 'href':
                self.hosts.add(urlparse(value).netloc.split(':')[0].lower())
                break
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this but it still won't print out the host, it completely ignores the <a href=..> tag in the file. Thoughts?

Comment: I had a bug in `handle_starttag` that should have triggered your exception handler. After the fix, I successfully added hosts from `<a href="...">` tags. You could print `parser.hosts` to see what's there.

Comment: interesting, the non-corrected one did not trigger the exception. I tried the corrected version and got "File "tohosts.py", line 31, in handle_starttag
    self.hosts.add(urlparse(attrs['href']).netloc.split(':')[0].lower())
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: That's the original error that I fixed... Make sure you are running the latest. If your original test didn't trigger an error, it means there was no 'a' tag in the html you used.